# How to execute code in other module context

Tags: python, class, binding, module, metaclass

With this code I want to get "**main**, **file**" and "**abc**", but I get ModelBase, Model etc...
I don't know what I can do. I define abc in b.py so i think it should execute in the global scope of b.py.

Module model.py:

```
class ModelBase(type):
    def __new__(cls,name,bases,attrs):
         module = attrs.pop('__module__');
         super_new = super(ModelBase,cls).__new__
         def test(cls):
             # want to print and references globals from Module b
             gl = globals()
             for i in gl:
                  print i
        new_class = super_new(cls,name,bases,{'__module__':module,'test':test})
        return new_class
class Model(object):
    __metaclass__ = ModelBase
```

Module b.py:

```
from model import *
class abc(Model):
    pass
tt = t();
tt.test();
```

Comment: [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) "Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called)."

Comment: Model don't see the globals of b.py! This is horrbile, so the question was what can I do? I know what the problem is, but this was not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the caller's globals by inspecting the call stack. However, pay attention to the remark [in the docs of `sys._getframe`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

> **CPython implementation detail:** This function should be used for
>   internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist
>   in all implementations of Python.

Anyway, the code you need to get the globals of the immediate caller is

```
sys._getframe(1).f_globals
```